# Why MATCH is not finding, at least, the items in RED at the end of the list?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm using `MATCH()` to find some values but some values are being found but others not.

At the end of the list you'll see values in RED that ARE in the Matching array but for some reason is not finding them. I'm just pointing to this values as a reference, there's more values not being found above.

Is not a format issue as the `=A=B` in this RED examples is giving `TRUE`.

What I'm doing wrong?

Any help will be appreciated.

[Download File HERE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3onrbufcrr197rs/Test.xlsx?dl=0)

Picture 01
[image]

Picture 02
[image]

Comment: Those cells must be dirty, although I cannot say in which way: if I edit the loookup value in the `Match` sheet, it is then correctly picked up. Just select the cell, press `F2` and then `Enter`.

Comment: Try to wrap the cell reference from MATCH in NUMBERVALUE function and give it a try. e.g. =MATCH(NUMBERVALUE(A340),.....)

Comment: Simple debugging:  the formula in cell Match!D354 is:
`=IF(ISERROR(INDEX(Items!$B$2:$B$1000,C354,1)), "", INDEX(Items!$B$2:$B$1000,C354,1))`
The reason it returns a blank is that cell C354 is blank. You need 270 in that cell (not 271).

Comment: PS.  You're using INDEX(), not MATCH().

Comment: To explain further, because C354 is blank, the first INDEX() returns the #VALUE error, which makes ISERROR() True, so the IF() returns "" (blank).